# SQL - How to select a column from a row that's related to MAX(other column)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables: `listings`, `bids`
A listing can have many bids

Here is the query I currently have:

```
Select all the listings, 
with their total number of bids and the highest bid amount
```

```
SELECT
    listings.title,
    COUNT(bids.id) AS number_of_bids,
    MAX(bids.amount) AS highest_bid_amount
    -- bids.date AS highest_bid_date
FROM 
    listings
LEFT JOIN 
    bids ON listings.id = bids.listing_id
GROUP BY
    -- bids.date,
    listings.title;
```

This works great!

But now I want to also add the date of the highest bid, however when I uncomment `-- bids.date`, I suddenly get multiple rows for the same listing, for each bid.

Before uncommenting `-- bids.date`:

```
listings.title      | number_of_bids | highest_bid_amount
----------------------------------------------------------
Example Listing 1   | 3              | 100
```

After uncommenting  `-- bids.date`:

```
listings.title      | number_of_bids | highest_bid_amount
----------------------------------------------------------
Example Listing 1   | 1              | 70
Example Listing 1   | 1              | 100
Example Listing 1   | 1              | 15
```

I get that its because I add `bids.date` to `GROUP BY` but is there any way to tell SQL "I want the bid date of the row that has `MAX(bid.amount)`"

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the count, this becomes a simple `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (listings.id)
       listings.title,
       bids.amount,
       bids.date
FROM listings
   LEFT JOIN bids
      ON listings.id = bids.listing_id
ORDER BY listings.id, bids.amount DESC;
```

To get the count in, you could add a subquery with a window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (listings.id)
       listings.title,
       b.amount,
       coalesce(b.count, 0),
       b.date
FROM listings
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT listing_id, amount, date,
                     count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY listing_id) AS count
              FROM bids) AS b
      ON listings.id = b.listing_id
ORDER BY listings.id, b.amount DESC;
```

Comment: Wouldn't you just use normal grouping and aggregation in the second option?

Comment: How can I order by b.amount or listings.created_at? because when I try to `ORDER BY listings.id, b.amount DESC` its actually not ordered correctly by b.amount descending

Comment: There was no such requirement in the question, but you can use my query as a subquery and add the `ORDER BY` clause you wish to the outer query.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe This works great! just one more question, I do have a `LIMIT 100` on the query, but I see that `ORDER BY b.count` causes a full table scan, where is without it, postgres will only calculate 100 rows. I get that it has to calculate the count of each row and then sort it. Is it something I have to live with? or is there a way to optimize this as well?

Comment: @TwoHorses I cannot answer that, since I can see neither the query nor its `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output. I guess that would be a different question.